# Functions how to take dictionary parameters

Tags: python

So here's my python code so far. I want to use these dictionaries and make them into a list of students. I am clueless as how to put run them into the `getAverage()` function and produce this result

```
 Name: Alice
 Homework: [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0]
 Quizzes: [82.0, 83.0, 91.0]
 Tests: [89.0, 97.0]
 For Alice the average is:91.14999999999999 

Name: Lloyd
Homework: [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]
Quizzes: [88.0, 40.0, 94.0]
Tests: [75.0, 90.0]
For Lloyd the average is:80.55 

Name: Tyler
Homework: [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0]
Quizzes: [0.0, 75.0, 78.0]
Tests: [100.0, 100.0]
For Tyler the average is:79.9
```

This is the code I've done so far:

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]}

rich = {
"name": "Rich",
"homework": [95.0, 93.0, 81.0, 94.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 55.0, 77.0],
"tests": [80.0, 95.0]}

josh = {
"name": "Josh",
"homework": [93.0, 94.0, 74.0, 99.0],
"quizzes": [87.0, 47.0, 92.0],
"tests": [70.0, 88.0]}

def average(n):
    count = float(len(n))
    total = float(sum(n))

    return total/count

def getAverage(**names):
    homework = average(names[homework])
    quizzes = average(names[quizzes])
    tests = average[names[tests]]
    return float((.1*homework +.3*quizzes + .6*tests)/3)

students = [rich, josh, lloyd]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your getAverage function to this (remove the **)

```
def get_average(names):
    homework = average(names['homework'])
    quizzes = average(names['quizzes'])
    tests = average(names['tests'])
    return (0.1*homework + 0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests) / 3

for student in [rich, josh, lloyd]:
    print student['name'], get_average(student)
```

A few other points:

- you have an indent issue with your `average` function
- prefer using PEP8 conventions (notably lower_case variables)

Answer (score 0):

You are close but you need to do a few things. First remove the ** from `getAverage`. Next remove the `/3` on the return. Also change the outer `[]` to `()` on this line `average[names[tests]]`. And then fix the indentation.

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]}

rich = {
"name": "Rich",
"homework": [95.0, 93.0, 81.0, 94.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 55.0, 77.0],
"tests": [80.0, 95.0]}

josh = {
"name": "Josh",
"homework": [93.0, 94.0, 74.0, 99.0],
"quizzes": [87.0, 47.0, 92.0],
"tests": [70.0, 88.0]}

alice = {
"name": "Alice",
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
"tests": [89.0, 97.0]}

taylor = {
"name": "Taylor",
"homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
"quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
"tests": [100.0, 100.0]}

def average(n):
  count = float(len(n))
  total = float(sum(n))
  return total/count

def getAverage(names):
  homework = average(names['homework'])
  quizzes = average(names['quizzes'])
  tests = average(names['tests'])
  return float((.1*homework +.3*quizzes + .6*tests))

students = [rich, josh, lloyd, alice, taylor]
for student in students:
  avg=getAverage(student)
  print('Name: '+student['name'])
  print('Homework: '+str(student['homework']))
  print('Quizzes: '+str(student['quizzes']))
  print('Tests: '+str(student['tests']))
  print('For '+student['name']+' the average is: '+str(avg)+'\n')
```